# Why is my custom aggregate function not returning data in the order I've specified?

Tags: pyqgis, intersection, aggregation

I have a polygon layer where many features intersect each other.
[image: screenshot of data, showing polygons labelled 'overlay' and 'prohibited' which overlap each other]
I want to flatten these overlaps and pick out attribute values according to a custom order. To do this, I've been using QGIS's Union tool in single layer mode, which breaks up the overlapped areas into new features which still overlap, but have identical geometry. Next, I use the Aggregate tool, with the grouping expression `@geometry`, to flatten these overlapping areas and aggregate their attribute values.

The possible values, in order of preference, are:

1. `prohibited`
2. `hearing`
3. `allowed`
4. `overlay`

I wrote a custom Python function to pick out the 'highest' value according to that order:

```
@qgsfunction(group='Aggregates', referenced_columns=[], handlesnull=True)
def myfunction(*values, **kwargs):
    unique_values = set(values)
    if "prohibited" in unique_values:
        return "prohibited"
    elif "hearing" in unique_values:
        return "hearing"
    elif "allowed" in unique_values:
        return "allowed"
    elif "overlay" in unique_values:
        return "overlay"
    else:
        return None
```

Since I put this function into the "Aggregates" group, it appears in the available functions in the Aggregate tool, in the same dropdown as `concatenate`, `sum`, `maximum`, etc.

[image: selecting custom function from dropdown]
[image: custom function selected in dropdown]

However, when I use it as an aggregate function with the Aggregate tool, it appears to just return the first value it encounters. Some example output, along with the `concatenated()` results on the same data:

| concatenated | myfunction |
| --- | --- |
| "prohibited,overlay" | prohibited |
| "overlay,overlay,allowed" | overlay |
| "overlay,overlay" | overlay |
| "prohibited,overlay" | prohibited |
| allowed | allowed |
| "prohibited,overlay,overlay" | prohibited |
| "prohibited,overlay" | prohibited |
| "overlay,overlay,allowed" | overlay |
| allowed | allowed |
| "overlay,overlay,overlay" | overlay |
| hearing | hearing |
| "overlay,overlay,overlay" | overlay |
| "overlay,prohibited" | overlay |

It appears that the function is returning the first item from the set of input values, rather than using the order I've defined with the `if...elif...else` statements. I don't understand why it would do this, because I'm casting to a `set` first, which should eliminate order as a consideration. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: hi, please edit the question to include the expression used.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca, I don't understand what you're asking—all expressions used are already included in the question.

Comment: i only see your python function, but don't know how are you calling it from the aggregate tool or any othe expressions engine like field calculator.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I added a little more detail for now. Tomorrow, when I'm back at that computer, I can add a screenshot to clarify things further.

Comment: I think that we are not able to create custom aggregate functions, and maybe it is better to use the concatenate aggregate function first, and then use a custom function in field calculator to get the value you want from that computed string (of comma separated values).